# Can't angular.copy to variable outside of function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, copy, angular-promise

I cannot seem to set my `product` variable properly from within my `getProduct()` function...

If I `console.log(product)` immediately after `angular.copy(products.data[i], product);`, it is set there correctly, however I cannot figure out why `var product = {};` on line 3 remains an empty object.

Any ideas what is going?

```
angular.module('APP').factory('productFactory', function($q, $http) {
    var products = [];
    var product = {};
    var getAllProducts = function(){
            return $http.get('./data/product.json')
                .then(function(response) {
                    angular.copy(response, products);

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                    return deferred.promise;
                });
        };

    var getProduct = function(id) {
        getAllProducts()
            .then(function(){
                for (var i = products.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if(products.data[i].id == id){
                        angular.copy(products.data[i], product);
                    }
                };
            })
        };

    return {
        getAllProducts: getAllProducts,
        getProduct: getProduct,
        products: products,
        product: product
    };
})
```

Comment: Question doesn't really make sense. If you see `product` is modified, how can it also be an empty object?

Comment: @charlietfl Within the scope of the function where I angular.copy `products.data[i]` to the `product` object, I see that `product` is correctly set. However, once I leave that scope, i.e., after the `getProduct()` function, `product` is again an empty object. I need to figure out a way to return that `product` from deep within the function so I can send it to my controller...

Comment: should always have same reference object using `productFactory.product`. `copy()` should not break that reference but if it does could try using `angular.extend()`

Comment: @charlietfl I just tried it with `angular.extend()`, but nothing changed...

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to access product in controller before `getProduct ()` is complete. A demo that replicates problem would help

Comment: Tangential comment: a `break` statement in your `for` loop would make it faster.